# iPhone Socket fails after a large number of data transfers

Tags: iphone, sockets

I've got an interesting issue with my socket test application.

I've set up a listening socket with an AcceptCallback function.  I've connected to the listening socket using :

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                   (CFStringRef) self.clientService.hostName, 
                                   self.clientService.port, 
                                   &myReadStream,
                                   &myWriteStream);
```

and I've send data back to the listening socket the myReadStream and myWriteStream, both of which I've cast to their NSStream equivalents.

The problem occurs after sending many separate packets of data.  The size of the packets do not matter, it's the number of packets (or the number of CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost creations) that seems to introduce the error.

After I send tons of packets (maybe around 100 or 200), when I try to send data over the NSOutputStream I get an error in the NSStreamEvent callback:

```
Operation could not be completed. (NSUnknownErrorDomain error 8.)
```

Then, if I try to create a new service and publish it on the network I get an error when I try to resolve the new address.  It gives me an error code of 10 in the NSNetService:didNotResolve delegate method (also, the error description is blank here).

It's almost as if the listening socket is "full" but it seems to think it's functioning fine because when I check CFSocketIsValid it returns true.

I'm stumped and have spent several hours trying to debug the situation... Any thoughts anybody?  Thanks.

Comment: To add more fuel to the fire, it would be helpful to list results running on the actual device itself. Networking performance definitely varies between the physical and the simulated.

Comment: Yea, I verified that the same problem happens on the device as well.  I get the same errors.  I just added a counter to the number of connections that are being made before it fails, and it makes 236 successful connections/transfers.  The 237th one always fails.  It's strangely close to 255, which makes me think that it might be some sort of memory leak with the socket retaining connections.  Not sure...

Comment: More clues: when the application is running on the device there are 239 successful transfers.  the 240th one always fails.  What differences are there between the socket on the iPhone and the socket on the simulator?

Comment: Are you bumping into open file limit? Check **ulimit -a**.

Comment: Nope, not a file limit issue. I'm not actually opening files to transfer data, I'm just sending raw data that I created in code.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I figured out the issue.

When connecting to a socket and initializing a read and write stream, as with the following:

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef) self.clientService.hostName, self.clientService.port, &myInputStream, &myWriteStream);
```

you need to make sure you set the following variable so that the lower level BSD stream closes when you close the CFStream or NSStream (in my case I cast the CFStream to an NSStream type):

```
CFReadStreamSetProperty(myReadStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(myWriteStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);
```

If you don't set this property the BSD stream never actually closes and you hit some sort of max number of socket connections - not sure exactly what the problem is.